# Why is my second button for a GUI not working?

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to get my second button to subtract the starting number, but I keep getting errors where ButtonListener1 is located (line 23 and 47) and I am unable to run my code.
I don't understand why it isn't working.
Please tel me if I'm supposed to add something to the button and operation in the private classes or the main class.

```
package addsubtract;

import javax.swing.JApplet;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class SubtractAdd extends JApplet {

    private int APPLET_WIDTH = 300, APPLET_HEIGHT = 35;
    private int num;
    private JLabel label;
    private JButton add;
    private JButton subtract;

    public void init ()
    {
        num = 50;

        add = new JButton ("Add");
        add.addActionListener (new ButtonListener());
        subtract = new JButton ("Subtract");
        subtract.addActionListener ((ActionListener) new ButtonListener1());

        label = new JLabel("Number: " + Integer.toString (num));

        Container cp = getContentPane();
        cp.setBackground (Color.PINK);
        cp.setLayout (new FlowLayout());
        cp.add(add);
        cp.add(subtract);
        cp.add(label);

        setSize (APPLET_WIDTH, APPLET_HEIGHT);

    }

    private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event)
        {
            num++;
            label.setText("Number: " + Integer.toString(num));

        }

    private class ButtonListener1 implements ActionListener
    {   
        public void actionPerfomred (ActionEvent event)    
        {
            num--;
            label.setText("Number: " + Integer.toString(num));

        }
    }  
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting

Comment: `but I keep getting errors ` What error is it and at which line?

Comment: We cannot help you untill you post your errors and where did they occur

Comment: It's the ButtonListener1, which is my second button for the function of subtracting.

Comment: It is line 23 and 47

Comment: Sorry, we can't see line numbers here. You need to [edit] your post with the actual error message content, please

Comment: you are trying to update `num` inside an inner class.  Those classes do not have visibility into variables declared outside of it.

Comment: `private class ButtonListener1` is inside of `class ButtonListener`. I think **that** is the problem that you are seeing, but there are others.

Comment: cricket_007 After I closed the private class ButtonListener, I fixed the error in Line 23, however my ButtonListener in the private class is still presenting an error.

Comment: Do you really need the private classes? Why can't you make `new ActionListener()` within the `init()` method?

Comment: Try declaring `num` like this: `public static int num;` and then inside the listeners you might be able to do something like: `SubtractAdd.num++` (or `--`)

Comment: I  have declared num as a static int so it can be reached thank you. Also, if I were to add the new ActionListener() in the init() method would I still need public void? I'm not too clear on ActionListener's function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you need the private classes. Plus, I believe they are causing you scoping issues (can't access `num` from within them).

Instead, you can make anonymous classes

```
add = new JButton ("Add");
add.addActionListener (new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event) {
        label.setText("Number: " + (++num));
    }
});
subtract = new JButton ("Subtract");
subtract.addActionListener (new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event) {
        label.setText("Number: " + (--num));
    }
});
```

---

Or have the class implement the interface

```
public class SubtractAdd extends JApplet implements ActionListener {

    public void init() {

        add = new JButton ("Add");
        add.addActionListener (this);
        subtract = new JButton ("Subtract");
        subtract.addActionListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event) {
        Object source = event.getSource();
        if (source == add) {
            label.setText("Number: " + (++num));
        } else if (source == subtract) {
            label.setText("Number: " + (--num));
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you so much! If you don't mind can you please explain why you put an override function? I just want to understand this as much as I can.

Comment: It's not necessary, but it helps to tell the compiler, "hey, this is being implemented differently than the default behavior". It is often added if you let the IDE auto-complete things